Why is the ACL mask generated from chmod if a default mask is already defined?
My plan is to grant permission to various groups and users with ACLs to a folder and all newly inherited objects.
In this case, RWX should also be granted to 'others' using chmod; otherwise, the mask of the ACL will be zero, and members of the groups won’t be able to access the files, even if they are delegated with (default) ACLs.
However, if 'others' have RWX, this will overwrite the other:-- ACL.
How can this conflict be resolved?
Parent folder:
# file: name
# owner: owner
# group: group
user::rwx
user:user:rwx
group::r-x
group:group:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:user:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:group:group:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---

ACL of a new file with root:root and chmod 600:
# file: name
# owner: owner
# group: group
user::rw-
user:user:rwx                #effective:---
group::r-x                      #effective:---
group:group:rwx      #effective:---
mask::---
other::---

Update
It seems that the ACL mask is generated based on group permissions from chown, even if a default mask is already defined with ACL.
In this case, there is little reason to keep the default mask function in the POSIX ACL standard..
